# Need android timer seconds to reset at 60

Tags: java, android, timer

I am building an app which uses a timer. I have a simple timer with a start and stop button. It works but I want the seconds to reset at 60. Currently it keeps going 61, 62, 63 etc. Can I get some help with this? Below are my start method, stop method and the runnable which has my timer.

```
private long startTime = 0;
private long timeInMilliSeconds = 0;
private long updatedTime = 0;
private long timeSwapBuff = 0;

start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
            }
        });

 stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliSeconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            }
        });

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timeInMilliSeconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliSeconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);

            timer.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) +
             ":" + String.format("%02d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the actual timer value have you considering printing `time%60` like this

```
int timeEllapsed = ... // the actual time spent for eg lets say 98
int timeToBePrinted = timeEllapsed%60 // the time you are going to show (38 seconds)
```

Comment: Perfect. Just changed String.format("%02d", secs) to String.format("%02d", secs%60) and it's working as expected. Thank you.

Comment: Intend on it, unfortunately I have to wait a couple minutes. :p